# URL structure changed after CMS update

Tags: url, content-management-system, prestashop, updates

I take in charge the update of an existing Prestashop 1.4.1.4 website. The url for a product was like:

> url/product.php?id_product=1322

But when I update to the new version 1.6.0.6, it became like:

> url/index.php?id_product=1372&controller=product&id_lang=2

When I type in the browser:

> url/product.php?id_product=1322

It leads me to 404 page.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`product.php` was deprecated in PrestaShop 1.5 and was removed in PrestaShop 1.6.

[Download PrestaShop 1.5](http://www.prestashop.com/en/developers-versions) and copy `product.php` to your PrestaShop root folder.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. However, do the copied product.php   not be removed the next update? I feel, even not an expert, Prestashop update strategies are really hurtful, esp for SEO.Do you agree?

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces Yes, unfortunately it will be removed during the next update. I agree, PrestaShop updates tend to break things.

Comment: so I respect the fact you answered and I upvoted, but I cannot accept this answer since it is: 1- a workaround, 2- adding product.pho is not working in my case.Thanks again

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces Do you still get 404?

Comment: No, I get a blank page with no source.

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces What is in the error log?

Comment: I will be answering your last comment when I will learn using error log. Anyways, the infor about file deprecation was the answer. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

add those lines on your .htaccess file

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_product=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^product.php$ index.php?id_product=%1&controller=product [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_category=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^category.php$ index.php?id_category=%1&controller=category [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_cms=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^cms.php$ index.php?id_cms=%1&controller=cms [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_manufacturer=([0-9]*)&p=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^manufacturer.php$ index.php?id_manufacturer=%1&p=%1=&controller=manufacturer [L,R=301]