# 'Home' category page not working after update

Tags: html, prestashop, updates, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.6

A prestashop website at version 1.4.1.4 was working with `category.php` file for category pages. The update to 1.6.0.6 unfortunatley deleted that file because it has been considered as deprecated. ([URL structure changed after CMS update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24012022/url-structure-changed-after-cms-update))

One consequence is the change in the URL structure.

from:

> url/category.php?id_category=6

to :

> url/index.php?id_category=6&controller=category&id_lang=2

So now, the first URL structure is  giving 404.

**The question:**
We don't know why all the category pages are working fine with the new strucure, except the page for `Home`(acceuil) category (the global parent category for all website categories). This `home` category page is giving 404 even with the new structure. In other words, the following url is not working:

> url/index.php?id_category=1&controller=category&id_lang=2

If I am not wrong, Prestashop gives id=1 by default to this `home` category? What is going wrong in your point of you? Any insights are highly appreciated.

**Edit based on Prestashop-Developper.co answer**

When I checked my database in PhpMyAdmin:

***After update from 1.4.1.4 to 1.6.0.6:***

I found neither a category with id=0 nor a category with id=2. I only find the category Home with id=1 and category Root with id=104. Root is parent of Home, but the field `is_root_category` for Home is set to 1!!!! I am really not understanding anything.

***Before update from 1.4.1.4 to 1.6.0.6:***

There is no Root category at all, and there is no `is_root_category` field at all.

***Note:***
These observations are based on the tables : ps_category, ps_category_group, ps_category_product, ps_category_shop before and after updtate =between 1.4.1.4 to 1.6.0.6.

Comment: Regarding the "Edit":
It's OK the "Root" to be 104, because it is added during the upgrade and set to the next autoincrement value for the id. It's also OK the "Home" directory to be with "is_root_category"=1, since "Root" is a category with special purpose.

As I said "Root" was added in PrestaShop 1.5, so it's normal to not be present before update from 1.4 to 1.6.

Comment: Thank you again.Then, `url/index.php?id_category=1&controller=category&id_lang=2` should work as the page for the category `Home`. Why it is still 404 in your opinion? the id of `Home` is 1 in my database.

Comment: Did you applied the changes from my answer?

Comment: @PrestaShop-Developer.com I applied them after you asked me to do and they are working perfectly. But honneslty I am not implementing it because I understood nothing in the code. I even didn't understood the principales behind. Please is it just a workaround to correct the behaviour of 1.6 and then might cause a problem in the next upgrade if core is corrected? Or is it a permanent solution? I feel the url shouldn't give 404, especially that all other categories (ids) work fine. Thank you for your invaluable time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PrestaShop 1.6 the Root & Home categories always return 404 (in PS 1.5 only Root returns 404), if you need to change that for Home category you must create an override for CategoryController.

Note that in PrestaShop 1.4 you have "Home" with id=1 and since 1.5 you have "Root" with id=1 and "Home" with id=2. Find the ID of the Home category.

Create file CategoryController.php in /override/controllers/front/ with the following content:

```
<?php 

class CategoryController extends CategoryControllerCore
{
    public function canonicalRedirection($canonicalURL = '')
    {
        if (Tools::getValue('live_edit'))
            return ;
        if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($this->category) || !$this->category->inShop() || !$this->category->isAssociatedToShop() || $this->category->id == Configuration::get('PS_ROOT_CATEGORY'))
        {
            $this->redirect_after = '404';
            $this->redirect();
        }
        if (!Tools::getValue('noredirect') && Validate::isLoadedObject($this->category))
            FrontController::canonicalRedirection($this->context->link->getCategoryLink($this->category));
    }
}
```

Make sure you delete /cache/class_index.php after creating the above file.

Comment: Can you please read my edit. I thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I have one problem: the products in thie category id=2 are not shown. How to solve this issue?