# Mass product category update (adding `home` category to all products) - Prestashop 1.6.0.6

Tags: php, sql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I observed that the count of all products is not equal to the number of products in category `home`. It is due to the fact that this biggest parent category was not always selected during product adding. So some products belong to `home` but others not.

While I need to display the correct number of products for the category `home` page, I was looking in the database for the columns that holds the categories but not found them in `ps_product` or  `ps_product_lang`.

what is the idea behind an sql query that can mass modify the appropriate fields in database so that all my products belong to category `home`.

Your usual help is appreciated. Thank you.

**Edit:**
I found that the table in database is `ps_category_product`. Is it the only one?

this table is like this:

```
+-------------+------------+----------+
| id_category | id_product | position |
+-------------+------------+----------+
|          11 |          1 |        1 |
|          11 |          2 |        2 |
|          11 |         10 |        3 |
+-------------+------------+----------+
```

I need maybe to create x lines (x= the number of products) . each line has id_category=1 and id_product= product id and position= position++. Is is the best approach?

Any help regarding how to implement it in sql?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign every product to the `Home` category with a simple SQL query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO ps_category_product SELECT 2, id_product, 0 FROM ps_product
```

`2` is normally the `id_category` value of the `Home` category, `0` is the `position`.

If you want unique `position` values then you need a more complex query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO ps_category_product SELECT 2, id_product, ((SELECT MAX(position) FROM ps_category_product WHERE id_category = 2) + (@inc := @inc + 1)) FROM ps_product INNER JOIN (SELECT @inc := 0) AS i
```

Comment: Waw, one line commande!!! SQL and yenshirak are great. I din't test it yet. I only feel it gonna work (even if I dont really understand the 2 and 0 in the query). MANY Thanks man.

Comment: When I do `SELECT 2 , id_product, 0 FROM  'ps_product'`  I receive three column: first one is all set to 2. the last one is 0. Do I need to change the values? What about the colomun position? shouldn' it contain incremental values?

Comment: It is working for me, but still all position values are 0 now for the home category products

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces `2` is the id of the `Home` category, `0` is the position. Having `0` for all positions isn't a problem, but if you want unique positions then you need a more complex query: `INSERT IGNORE INTO ps_category_product SELECT 2, id_product, ((SELECT MAX(position) FROM ps_category_product WHERE id_category = 2) + (@inc := @inc + 1)) FROM ps_product INNER JOIN (SELECT @inc := 0) AS i`. For this to work you have to remove the previously inserted rows.

Comment: But me I have category `Home` with `1` as id (PS 1.6.0.6). The `2` gives a 404. That's why I edited the answer. It will be more detailed if you add a N.B indicating that `2` is sometimes the id of `Home`. Second, Thank you very much for the science I learned behind your two smart queries (unique position might be useful in the future).

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces Are you sure that the `id_category` of `Home` is `1` for you? I made a fresh install right now and `Root` is `1`, `Home` is `2`.

Comment: Fresh install will say nothing in this case. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023989/home-category-page-not-working-after-update , the edit of OP describes exacly my situation. Thank you for your time.